# Response when your boss thanks you

Tags: vocabulary, correspondence

What should be your response when your boss thanks you for using his own resource allotted to you and you respect your boss and cannot respond him like *It's ok* or *you're welcome*.

Comment: Under no circumstances say, "Yep." That drives me crazy when people use that as a response to a sincere thank you.

Comment: For those kind of questions you can also try to ask at Quora.com

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some appropriate responses would be:

> - "My pleasure."
> - "Don't mention it."
> - "You're [most] welcome."
> - "I'm glad I could help/be of help."
> - "Oh [no], thank you! Always at your service."
> - "It was not a problem at all. [I'm] glad I could be of assistance."

And, of course, you could use "sir" or "ma'am" to make your response even more polite.

Comment: I would strike "Don't mention it" from the list.  It can sound like you are refusing to accept your boss's thanks.

Comment: *Glad to be of your service, my* [ *dear* ] [ *master* | *overlord* | *boss* | *commander* | *captain* | ...]

Comment: @Eric: "Don't mention it" is very commonly in use here, along with "No problem", both having the same intent, that it needed no thanks.

Comment: @Orbling: I'm aware of both of those and their common usage.  Most people don't realize though that they downplay the thanks being offered though, which can be construed as rude.  Look at it this way: someone is happy with something you have done and is taking the time to verbally express this to you.  It can be seen as you telling them that no thanks is necessary and that they shouldn't have bothered with wanting to let you know that they were grateful.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: I tend to find "So when's my payrise?" or "I should think so too" effective. ;-)

Comment: @Eric: Yes, I realise what you were getting at.  Though I do not think the vast majority of people would interpret it that way, as the expression is so standard.  Particularly in England were modesty is generally expected.

Comment: @Eric: I think you are reading this too literally... "Don't mention it" is quite standard, as @Orbling pointed out, (especially in the UK and UK-friendly climes) and it is considered one of the most polite responses to a "Thank you". It's equivalent to the American "You're welcome", in this regard.

Comment: @Orbling: Haha, "So when's the raise coming?"/"You owe me one!"/"Let's have dinner on you." Certainly depends on relationship with the said boss. I don't use "don't mention it" or "you're welcome" too often, even with my superiors. Usually, "Oh no!" spills out; maybe followed by "not a problem" or "it was fun", depending on the context.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: I tend to actually speak in acronyms slightly, and say "NP".

Comment: You could say: "Yessssssssssss, praisssse me, masssssster..." But yeah, as @JimiOke points out, it depends on your relationship with your boss. I could do this, but I have a personality that can carry it off.

Answer (score 4):

I go with "It's my job" or I don't even answer. I get paid to do what I do. Too many thank you's are meaningless to me. Show me thanks in form of a raise or bonus. Then I'll say thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't go wrong with, "You're welcome." It's short, it's to the point, and it's sufficiently formal. If you need to dress it up a bit further you can add "glad to help" at the end.

I would worry that too long or too flowery of a response might be interpreted as being condescending or mocking, especially if you're responding in written correspondence where the intonation of the response is hard to judge.

Let me put it this way, if I thanked a subordinate and she responded with something verbose like, "I am always most happy to serve you," or, "It is always my pleasure to come to your aid," I would think that bordered between weird and condescending.

Comment: Can I say "Always welcome!"?

Comment: @misho: To me, "Always welcome" sounds a bit off. It's not something I'd expect a native speaker to say.

Comment: Or better yet, "Anytime."

Comment: Only Americans say "you're welcome". Here in Britain it is considered to be very bad form.

Comment: @fdb, what is considered a polite response if someone thanks you for your effort? Do you say nothing or is there some other phrase that is considered a tactful response?

Comment: I might say "no problem", or "any time".

Comment: @fdb: That is considered the polite response even when your boss thanks you (presuming you are not on colloquial terms with her)? And what if it was a very formal setting, e.g., at some state function and the Prime Minister thanks you for your service, or whatever?

Comment: @fdb You say "Here in Britain", where exactly in Britain is it considered "very bad form"? I cannot think of the situation where somebody would say "You're welcome" and receive a "How dare you?" response. Maybe if you are writing something very formal... Let's say there's an earth quake somewhere and Britain sends aid, to which that country issues a statement "The people of Elbonia thank you", then prime minister probably shouldn't say "You're welcome", but in almost every other case, it's fine.